# postgres full text search query on large table not using index

Tags: postgresql, full-text-indexing

Full text search query

```
SELECT id
 FROM (
   SELECT id, 
   ts_rank_cd(setweight(to_tsvector('english', lower(title)), 'A') || 
   setweight(to_tsvector('english', lower(body)), 'B'), 
   plainto_tsquery('english', 'query')) AS rank
   FROM table) s
 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

Create index command

```
CREATE INDEX fts_index ON table USING 
gin((setweight(to_tsvector('english', lower(title)), 'A') || 
setweight(to_tsvector('english', lower(body)), 'B')));"
```

The table contains over 90,000 rows but postgres chooses to do a sequential scan, which takes a couple of minutes, instead of using the index.

Answer (score 0):

The index cannot be used.

The only use of an index here would be to support the `ORDER BY` clause, and for that the index would have to be a regular B-Tree index on the *complete* expression that is named `rank` in your query.

Comment: But the _complete_ expression named rank in my query includes the search phrase.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The call to `ts_rank_cd(tsvector, tsquery)` is missing.

Comment: Is there a way to use setweight and still use indexes?

Comment: As far as I know, index usage is independent of weights. They are used for ranking.